# How to make a windows form fill the entire screen

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap, picturebox

I've got a function the creates a Bitmap and I pass this Bitmap to a function the creates a new Windows Form, a new PictureBox and I set the Image property of the PictureBox to the Bitmap.

Add the PictureBox to the new WindowsForm then .Show(); the new Form.

I'm attempting to fill the entire screen with the new Form and fill the new Form with the new PictureBox and if there is any overflow I would like to have scroll bars; however, I cannot get the new Form to fill the window nor can I get the scroll bars to show.

Any suggestions?

```
void ShowWindow(Bitmap elevation)
{

    Form f = new Form();
    f.Text = "CAD Drawing";
    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
    pb.Image = elevation;
    pb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    f.Controls.Add(pb);
    f.BringToFront();
    f.Show();
}
```

[image: The current result]

Answer (score 1):

```
    void ShowWindow(Bitmap elevation)
    {

        Form f = new Form();
        f.Text = "CAD Drawing";
        f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        p.AutoScroll = true;
        p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Image = elevation;
        pb.Width = elevation.Width;
        pb.Height = elevation.Height;
        //pb.Focus();

        p.Controls.Add(pb);

        f.Controls.Add(p);
        f.BringToFront();
        f.Show();
    }
```